# Is Oom-pah and Boom-Chick the same thing?

Tags: guitar, theory, piano, rhythm

In guitar travis picking style they talk about Boom-Chick alternating bass pattern, in piano and trumpets they talk about Oom-pah bass. Is it basically the same thing? I think they both talk about alternating the bass note between the first and fifth of whatever chord you're playing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that though they are similar ideas, boom-chick involves alternating between playing a bass note (boom) and a rhythm chord (chick) whereas Oom-Pah describes playing alternating bass notes, apart from any rhythm part. I usually associate Oom-Pah with Tuba and playing octave intervals in the bass register. I've not heard it used associated with trumpet, but that could just be my limited experience with those instruments.